# How to convert the auth response into array of objects?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication, xlsx-populate

I am trying to get the response of the users using auth function and i have to create an excel sheet using the xlsx-populate library and i am able to convert that into an array of objects as the limit is 1000 so there are multiple arrays of objects. and i am not able to figure out how can i do this problem.in this problem, i am simply fetching results using auth and try to get the results into an array of objects. and i am also tried to use the objects to pass into the excel sheet but it gives the excel sheet with last 1000 queries response

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const momentTz = require("moment-timezone");
const XlsxPopulate = require("xlsx-populate");
momentTz.suppressDeprecationWarnings = true;
const {
  alphabetsArray
} = require("./constant");
var start = momentTz().subtract(4, "days").startOf("day").format();
var start = momentTz(start).valueOf();
const end = momentTz().subtract(1, "days").endOf("day").format();
const  listAllUsers = async(nextPageToken) =>{
  const [workbook] = await Promise.all([
    XlsxPopulate.fromBlankAsync()
  ]);
  const reportSheet = workbook.addSheet("Signup Report");
  workbook.deleteSheet("Sheet1");

  reportSheet.row(1).style("bold", true);
  [
    "Date",
    "TIME",
    "Phone Number"
  ].forEach((field, index) => {
    reportSheet.cell(`${alphabetsArray[index]}1`).value(field);
  });
  let count = 0
  // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.


  const data = [];
  admin
    .auth()
    .listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then (async  (listUsersResult) => {

      listUsersResult.users.forEach((userRecord) =>{

        const time = userRecord.metadata.creationTime;

        const timestamp = momentTz(time).valueOf();
        //   console.log(timestamp)


        if (timestamp >= 1585704530967 ) {
          console.log(time);
          let column = count+2;
          count++;
          data.push(userRecord.toJSON())
          reportSheet.cell(`A${column}`).value(time);

          reportSheet.cell(`C${column}`).value(userRecord.phoneNumber);

        }
      });

   console.log(JSON.stringify(data))//this is the array of the object and i am getting after 1000 response 
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {

        // List next batch of users.
        listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
        await workbook.toFileAsync("./SignUp.xlsx");
      }
    })
    // .catch(function (error) {
    //   console.log("Error listing users:", error);
    // });
    // const datas = []
    //   datas.push(data)
    //   console.log(datas)
    return ;
}
// Start listing users from the beginning, 1000 at a time.
listAllUsers();


and the output i am getting is like this 
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
i want to convert this into a single array of response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a race condition. When you perform your `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` your listUserQuery is in progress (and in async mode) and you don't have yet the answer when you print the array. Thus the array is empty.

Try this (I'm not sure of this optimal solution, I'm not a nodeJS dev)

```
  admin
    .auth()
    .listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then (async  (listUsersResult) => {

      listUsersResult.users.forEach((userRecord) =>{

        const time = userRecord.metadata.creationTime;

        const timestamp = momentTz(time).valueOf();
        //   console.log(timestamp)


        if (timestamp >= 1585704530967 ) {
          console.log(time);
          let column = count+2;
          count++;
          data.push(userRecord.toJSON())
          reportSheet.cell(`A${column}`).value(time);

          reportSheet.cell(`C${column}`).value(userRecord.phoneNumber);

        }
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data))//this is the array of the object and i am getting after 1000 response 
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {

        // List next batch of users.
        listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
        await workbook.toFileAsync("./SignUp.xlsx");
      }
    );
```

Comment: i am getting the output but for the result of 1000 and again an array of 1000 but i want to store all the values inside an array. like i have 5000 documents and i am getting 1000 document at a time so to fetch the result of 5000 documents there is 5 array and i want to store the array inside a single array